# Font size from screen resolution ? portable C++?

Tags: c++, fonts, size, resolution, dpi

I have a C++ application and I use ImGUI for building my UI !

The problem is that on my laptop the default font size is good (default is 13 pixels), but on another computer (with bigger resolution), the text is so small that I can't read it !

I notice that other applications have a "bigger" font in this situation.

So, is there a way to compute a "scale factor" for my font depending of the monitor resolution ?

I'm looking for a portable C++ solution !

Thanks for your help

Comment: There is no "portable C++ solution". Portable C++ doesn't even know what a monitor or font is, let alone what the monitor's resolution are. These are all provided by various libraries. The best you'll get is if this ImGUI library provides this functionality across the platforms it supports.

Comment: "Portable" is relative. It all depends on your GUI library, since C++ doesn't define these things.

Comment: But how does frameworks like QT (and other) are doing to resize their fonts then ?

Comment: The standard way to specify a font is work from a point size.  Which has a unit of inches, not pixels.  So somebody with a high resolution monitor increases the dots-per-inch setting and automagically gets a larger font.  [Read this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/74299).

Comment: I agree... but the graphic system work with pixels... so there is a way to convert theses size into pixels. But how ?